# Loop through directories in a given path until an existing directory is reached

Tags: bash, terminal, shell-script, path, directory-listing

I have an unknown path given by the user where I would create a file.
Since I don't have write permissions I need to find the first existing dir in the path going from inside to outside and check for write permissions.

For instance `foo/moo/doo`

I've tried

```
for d in "$dirpath"/ ; do
    "dir=$d"
done
```

But it doesn't seems to work

So I must loop trough the path whether it's absolute or relative check each node whether it exist and if it's a directory indeed and if so return **it**

or if not return

- perhaps top directory if the path is absolute ( not sure if there's always a concrete dir in unix on top of absolute path)
- Current directory to the relative path

Any ideas appreciate your kind help

Comment: `"dir=$d"` does not do what you expect. you need to quote just the value, not the entire assignment.

Comment: @l0b0 how do I get just the value?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Could you please update your question to include an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to find (1) a directory like `./unknown/partial/path/foo/moo/doo`? or (2) the longest existing path from the set `./foo/moo/doo`, `./foo/moo`, `./foo`, `.`? or (3) something else?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I need to loop the path from the inside to the outside which means to start with `doo` and when I reach an existing dir in the path I must stop and then check for write permissions. I can't check non existing folder for write permissions.
The path could be anything because the script user gives it.

Comment: So like (2), right?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes like (2)

Comment: does `if [[ -d "$dirpath" ]]; then echo "$dirpath is a directory"; fi` do what you need? I still find your problem description very unclear.

Comment: @glennjackman The directory might not exist so I need to loop until i find existing one in the path and then check for write permission to create the rest non existing

Comment: "to create the rest non existing" – see `mkdir -p`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski But how to check whether I have write permissions for the path? I run 3rd party scripts in the directory so no super user.

Comment: If you don't have write permissions, you can't "create the rest non existing" anyway, can you? Maybe unless the non-writable directory is empty and you can remove it; or it's your directory and you can give yourself permissions. If I were you, I would [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). If `mkdir -p` returns "permission denied", assume there's a reason the permissions are what they are and the best your script can do is throw an error; then you investigate by hand. Any cumbersome script logic may backfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that finds the first existing directory in a path starting from the deepest location in the path.

```
function findConcreteDirInPath() {
  local dirpath="$1"
  local stop="no"
  while [ $stop = "no" ] ; do
    if [ -d "$dirpath" ]; then
      local stop="yes"
    else
      local dirpath=$(dirname "$dirpath")
      if [ "$dirpath" = "" ] ; then
        local stop="yes"
        exit 1;
      fi
    fi
  done

  echo "$dirpath"
}
```

Here's an usage example

```
aPath="/var/doo/moo"
concreteDir=$(findConcreteDirInPath $aPath)

if [ $concreteDir != "." ]; then
  echo -e "First concrete dir in \"$aPath\" path is: \"$concreteDir\""
  # Check whether current user have write permissions for the directory
  if [ -w $concreteDir ]; then
    echo -e "\"$(whoami)\" user can write in \"$concreteDir\""
  else
    echo  -e "\"$(whoami)\" user can NOT write in \"$concreteDir\""
  fi
else
  echo -e "No concrete dir for the given \"$aPath\" path"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick solution

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(realpath "$1")
stop=no
while [ $stop = no ] ; do
    if touch "$dir/this.$$" ; then
        rm "$dir/this.$$"
        echo "You can create in $dir!"
        stop=yes
    else
        dir=${dir%/*}
        if [ "$dir" = "" ] ; then
            echo "You are not allowed to write anywhere."
            stop=yes
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: 10x your answered helped me to make a function that does the job

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the solution as such.